# Proguard Obfuscation for Android App in Eclipse problem

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using the android 2.3.3 sdk. I have added the proguard.config=proguard.cfg line to default.properties in my project. I have ran the Export Wizard in Eclipse successfully, however the dump, mapping, seeds and usage file have not been created. Could you tell me where does eclipse output these files, they are not in the root or the bin folder of my project. Am i missing something? Thanks

Comment: I'm try to obfuscate the code to stop reverse engineering, I just can't find the files to decode the obfuscation if they are even being generated.

Comment: ProGuard obfuscate only when you do Export Signed Application Package

Answer (score 1):

Did you add:

```
-dump proguard/class_files.txt 
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt 
-printusage proguard/unused.txt 
-printmapping proguard/mapping.txt
```

to the proguard.cfg?

The output should show in the directory

```
<project>/proguard/
```

Answer (score 0):

In all projects where I used proguard, the proguard output files go to a directory named "proguard" at the project root

Comment: This directory is never created, have you any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project (Project->Clean), then Android Tools->Export Signed Package?

Comment: I have used Android Tools->Export Signed Package with the same results. This have work for me before on another project, I just can't see why its not working now.